# Mailchimp with cakephp

Tags: cakephp, mailchimp

I am download sample code from mailchimp site and copy paste in my c:/xampp folder now i am run the index.php file but i got following warning and error

> Warning:
>   include(C:\xampp\htdocs\Dropbox\Demos\mailchimp\mcapi2-php-examples-master/Vendor/pear-pear.cakephp.org/CakePHP\Cake\bootstrap.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Dropbox\Demos\mailchimp\mcapi2-php-examples-master\webroot\index.php
>   on line 107
>
> Warning: include(): Failed opening
>   'C:\xampp\htdocs\Dropbox\Demos\mailchimp\mcapi2-php-examples-master/Vendor/pear-pear.cakephp.org/CakePHP\Cake\bootstrap.php'
>   for inclusion (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Dropbox\Demos\mailchimp\mcapi2-php-examples-master\webroot\index.php
>   on line 107
>
> Fatal error: CakePHP core could not be found. Check the value of CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH in APP/webroot/index.php. It should point to
>   the directory containing your \cake core directory and your \vendors
>   root directory. in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Dropbox\Demos\mailchimp\mcapi2-php-examples-master\webroot\index.php
>   on line 114

Now I am install composer and create phar file and try to update with composer update command but following error display

http://prntscr.com/5d2cgw

Comment: Are you attempting to use the more-complex Mailchimp API functionality, or are you just hoping to send emails?

Answer (score 0):

In composer.json file change require property with this lines

```
"require": {
        "cakephp/cakephp": "2.5.*",
        "mailchimp/mailchimp": ">=2.0.0"
    },
```